# Decorator for a class method

Tags: c++

Supposing I have a function (a decorator) that measures the duration of given function:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void measure(void (*f)()) {
    time_t tBegin = time(NULL);
    f();
    time_t tEnd = time(NULL);
    cout << "Duration: " << (tEnd - tBegin) << " sec" << endl;
}
```

And I want to measure the duration of a method of a class. For example:

```
class Myclass {
private:
    double _d;

public:
    Myclass(double d) : _d(d) {}

    void run() {
        measure(m);
    }

    void m() const {
        usleep(1000000 * _d);
    }
};

int main() {
    Myclass obj(2.0);
    obj.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Such implementation leads to the error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function
```

Is there a way in C++ to implement it correctly? It's supposed not to modify the external function `measure` and the measured method is exactly non-static (it uses data of the instance). The measurement should be inside of the method `run`.

I need solution for C++ 1998/2003 Standard.

Comment: Pass in a lambda?

Comment: `std::function` that is

Comment: A full code please.

Comment: SO is not a full code generator

Comment: Is C++11 (or higher) okay?

Comment: I need solution for C++ 1998/2003 Standard.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: Unless you want to deal with a bunch of static stuff that isn't quite threadsafe, or robust in general, I don't think this will work without changing `measure`

Comment: @Fomalhaut: What I mean is something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f7fdd5c62eb057). Which is basically me emulating a C++11 lambda for a pretty specific use case (wrapping a call of a const member function)

Comment: @Fomalhaut: Is there any way I can improve my answer? Did you find something else that worked for your use case?

Comment: @AndyG Unfortunately it hasn't solved my task... I want to keep the exact type signature of the function.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: Did you look at the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f7fdd5c62eb057) portion of my answer? I didn't change the type signature of the function at all.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change `measure` to a function template to allow you to use any callable, not just a function.
2. Use a lambda function in `run`.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

template <typename F>
void measure(F f) {
    time_t tBegin = time(NULL);
    f();
    time_t tEnd = time(NULL);
    std::cout << "Duration: " << (tEnd - tBegin) << " sec" << std::endl;
}

class Myclass {
private:
    double _d;

public:
    Myclass(double d) : _d(d) {}

    void run() {
        measure([=](){m();});
    }

    void m() const {
        usleep(1000000 * _d);
    }
};

int main() {
    Myclass obj(2.0);
    obj.run();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Since,  you are not allowed to modify `measure`, you can use a helper class template and a function template to make it possible for you to use any callable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void measure(void (*f)()) {
    time_t tBegin = time(NULL);
    f();
    time_t tEnd = time(NULL);
    std::cout << "Duration: " << (tEnd - tBegin) << " sec" << std::endl;
}

template <typename F>
struct MeasureFunctor
{
   static F* f_;
   static void run(){(*f_)();}
};

template <typename F> F* MeasureFunctor<F>::f_ = nullptr;

template <typename F>
void measure(F f) {
   MeasureFunctor<F>::f_ = &f;
   measure(MeasureFunctor<F>::run);
}

class Myclass {
private:
    double _d;

public:
    Myclass(double d) : _d(d) {}

    void run() {
        measure([=](){m();});
    }

    void m() const {
        usleep(1000000 * _d);
    }
};

int main() {
    Myclass obj(2.0);
    obj.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP is not allowed to change `measure`.

Comment: Sorry. I'm interested in solution without modifying of `measure`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned you're stuck with C++03 the answer is that without changing the signature of `method`, you're stuck with some `static` tomfoolery:

The gist of what I'm about to do is to mimic a C++11 style lambda for your specific use case (wrapping a call to a `const` member function with empty parameter list that returns `void`). You could do some work to make this code a little more general.

First I'll post the wrapper code, then I'll break it down:

```
template<class T, void(T::*PTR)()const, size_t I>
struct bind_member
{
    typedef void(*fn_type)();
    explicit bind_member(const T* _ptr) 
    {
        ptr = _ptr;
    }
    static void func(void)
    {
        (ptr->*PTR)();
    }
    operator fn_type()
    {
        return &func;
    }
    private:
    static const T*  ptr;
};

template<class T, void(T::*PTR)()const, size_t I>
const T* bind_member<T, PTR, I>::ptr = NULL;
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f7fdd5c62eb057)

---

#### Breakdown

The template arguments on our `bind_member` struct (`template<class T, void(T::*PTR)()const, size_t I>`) are for

- `T` is the type of class whose member function pointer we're wrapping. This becomes `Myclass` in your example
- `void(T::*PTR)()const` is the ugly syntax for a const member function pointer on `T`. The name of this template argument is `PTR`
- `size_t I` is included so that you can have multiple instances of your `Myclass` use the same lambda to wrap the same function, only that you'll need to give each instance its own unique id to avoid them stepping on each other's toes. (In our example we only have one instance, so I gave it `0` instead of making some complicated static counter/member id combination).

Within `bind_member` we have our constructor that accepts a pointer to an instance of a class. This is solely for setting the `static` class member.

Next we have `func`, which is the wrapped way we will call `Myclass::m`. If `m` accepted an `int`, then so would `func`. Again, you could do some fancy templating to make this all a little more generic.

Now here's the trick:
We provide an implicit conversion of our `bind_member` struct to a C-style function pointer, and we do so in the form of

```
typedef void(*fn_type)();
operator fn_type()
{
    return &func;
}
```

Which works because our `func` type is `static` so it doesn't require an instance of the class and therefore does not appear as a member function pointer. The `typedef` is for convenience, it's specifying the type of `func`, which is that it accepts no arguments and returns `void`.

Now onto actually calling within `Myclass`:

```
void run() 
{
    bind_member<Myclass, &Myclass::m, 0> b(this);
    measure(b);
}
```

I provide the template arguments as described above to create an instance of `bind_member`, passing `this` as an argument so that `bind_member` can call the passed function (`m`). I can pass `&Myclass::m` as a non-type template parameter because function pointers are pointer types, which are integral types, meaning they have addresses, so we can use template parameters to get those addresses.

Finally, we can pass `b` to our `measure` function and we're done.

### Conclusion

Upgrade to C++11 (or above) if you can, and write a lambda like some of the other answers here describe. Otherwise, beg to change the signature of `measure` to be templated on a callable, and then we can wrap `Myclass::m` a little easier. If all else fails, use the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

I also would prefer a lambda (and a std::function as parameter for measure), but since you cannot change that, what about this idea:

1. Make `m()` static.
2. Add a static member to MyClass that takes a reference to the current MyClass instance that is running `measure`. You must set this everytime before you call `m()`. Also, think about thread safetiness.
3. In `m()` you can then use this reference to get to `_d`. Alternatively, you could even store the value of `_d` in a static member var to have it available in `m()`. Depends on what you actually need from `MyClass`.

This approach would allow to measure only one invocation at a time. For parallel execution of multiple `measure()` calls you could use thread-local-storage for the reference you set in step 2.